# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904, but only randomly

Tags: sharepoint-server, exception

SharePoint 2016 OnPremise, all works fine, but sometimes only in one list, when adding a new item, after saving when it returns to the standard view, I get `Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904`.

Uls says:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified network name is no longer available    

SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2: UserPrincipalName=i:0).w|s-1-5-21-2025429265-688789844-725345543-18654, AppPrincipalName= ,pSqlClient=<null> ,bstrUrl=http://portal/mySite ,bstrListName={A9A7F119-9D25-4CDD-A59D-BD5F8AB58C85} ,bstrViewName=<null> ,bstrViewXml=<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Datum" Ascending="FALSE" /><FieldRef Name="BegonnenUm" Ascending="FALSE" /></OrderBy><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Author" /><Value Type="Integer"><UserID Type="Integer" /></Value></Eq></Where></Query><Aggregations Value="On"><FieldRef Name="Dauer" Type="SUM" /><Fi ,fSafeArrayFlags=SAFEARRAYFLAG_AUTOHYPERLINK

Error while executing web part: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView)     
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.get_Count()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments selectArguments, String aggregateString, Boolean wantReturn, BaseXsltListWebPart webpart, SPListItem& listItem, SPListItemCollection& listItems, String[]& fieldList)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigatorInternal()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigator()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean bDeferExecuteTransform) 1bbd449f-5801-b098-2604-475e9b3793d4
```

If I refresh the page it works.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to check a couple of things - main problem with this is your SQL connection with the SharePoint server is not stable. Check the SQL server windows log - there you will get more details about the error.

But in general, verify the below:

- Network connectivity between SQL Server and SharePoint - mostly it is not stable, check with your network team.
- If you have **AG** group cluster (**listener**) configured in the SQL server - the primary database sometimes will be detached from the **Availability Group** (AG) but it will re-connect again due to fluctuation in the network connectivity.
- Try to increase SQL connection timeout property
- Finally try doing the IIS reset.

Comment: ok thanks, I will check it. But how is it possible that I have this problem only on this single list, I have for sure more than 200 in my farm.

Comment: Are you sure it is only for one list or all lists under a single content db? AG group issue occurs in the content db level.

Comment: I have only one ContentDB and yes, only for this list.

Comment: Ohhk.. In that case I think you can try doing the iis reset, that might fix.

Comment: Unfortunately, restarting the IIS didn't help. I will restart the server as soon as possible